# Understanding Error Message Deploying Flask app to Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

Im trying to deploy a basic Flask app to Heroku from a Github repo. Im using Heroku's native Github deployment integration. I linked the repo, enabled automatic deploys and deployed the current branch but the app wont work live. Im getting an application error and when i look at the Heroku logs I get the following message which i dont quite understand. Any leads to figure it out would be helpful.

Thanks!

```
2021-09-06T17:15:27.415330+00:00 heroku[run.3430]: Awaiting client
2021-09-06T17:15:27.436035+00:00 heroku[run.3430]: Starting process with command `heroku logs --tail`
2021-09-06T17:15:31.885141+00:00 heroku[run.3430]: Process exited with status 127
2021-09-06T17:15:31.931116+00:00 heroku[run.3430]: State changed from up to complete
2021-09-06T17:16:35.359596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=flask-nasa-img-of-the-day.herokuapp.com request_id=4dc72195-dbe7-4ea5-9e5b-2a fwd="67.244.234.456" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-06T17:16:36.030600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flask-nasa-img-of-the-day.herokuapp.com request_id=0ee99103-4468-4358-89d3-28 fwd="67.244.234.456" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile
`web: gunicorn app:app`

requierements.txt

```
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==8.0.1
Flask==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.2
importlib-metadata==4.8.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
python-dotenv==0.19.0
requests==2.26.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
urllib3==1.26.6
Werkzeug==2.0.1
zipp==3.5.0
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


# home page
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # api_key = credentials.API_KEY
    # api_key = environ.get('API_KEY')
    api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")
    req = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=" + api_key)
    data = json.loads(req.content)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of the logs? Does your application work locally? Were previous builds working?

Comment: Yep, in the past i had this error as well: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>. I wodner if its the Procfile? I have it as 'web: gunicorn app:app'. In terms of working locally yes it does work locally. No previous builds working, this is the first time working it out.